# Handle event of "GO" button in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a webview loads my local html file. It has many textfield so I want when press "GO" button on iOS keyboard to step to next textfield. but I can't catch that event of "Go" button. Is there any solution

Comment: Have you created your GO button in html file?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited. "Go" button on keyboard. Not from html

Comment: That will be bad UX. "Go" button isn't for hopping textfields.

Comment: So we can't do anything with it?